# Regular expression to limit multiple occurrence of any character to two

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for a regular expression to limit multiple occurrence of any character in a string to two.

eg: `Reallllly like` and `Sooooooo good` should be converted to `Really like` and `So good`.

Comment: But it would actually end up `soo good`

Comment: Convert `Sooooooo good` to `So good` is easy, but convert `Reallllly like` to `Really like` is difficult.

Comment: @KevinGuan: I would actually think vice versa. :) Unless your rule is 3+ -> 1, 2 -> 2 (which is weird. possible, but weird.)

Comment: @Amadan Yes, so maybe we need a dictionary. I mean an English dictionary :P

Comment: @KevinGuan: Even then not trivial. There are many possible ways to reduce `MMMiiisssiiisssiiipppiii` (Misisipi, Mmiissiissiippii, Mississippi, MMississippi, Miisiisiipii...), so it would probably be pruned search over a binary tree, over the dictionary.

Comment: @Amadan Hmm...like `toooo` can be `to` or `too`?

Comment: @KevinGuan: Yes, it can...

Comment: @Amadan Well, I think OP really need a spell-checker, use regex to do this maybe will make some mistake, except there are some rules.

Comment: @Manu it is fine even if it end up "soo good". my objective is to clean tweets and match keywords. It is ok even if the words are not grammatically correct.

Answer (score 3):

Replaces sequences of three or more same characters by only two.

```
re.sub(r'(.)\1{2,}', r'\1\1', "Realllllly goooood")
```

*Edit: fixed typo.*

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it with a regex, but `itertools.groupby` works well:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> g = groupby('reallllly goood')
>>> ''.join(''.join(list(x)[:2]) for _,x in g) 
>>> 'really good'
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer from @pacholik is almost right.

Proper expression:

```
re.sub(r'(.)\1{2,}', r'\1\1', "Realllllly goood")
```

We replace substrings where more then 3 occurrences, not 4 (*first `(.)` and 2 or more repeats `\1{2,}` replaced with 2 repeats of the 1st character `\1\1`*).